# C# Set variable from numbers on either side of a comma?

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers

I have a textbox where the user would enter a set of numbers seperated by commas, ("1, 2, 3 , 4"). I need to set a variable for each one of these numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: Need more context than this.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not store it in an array?

```
string val = textbox.text;
string[] arr = val.Split(',');
```

example

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
         string s = "1,2,3,4";
         string[] numbers = s.Split(',');
         foreach (string num in numbers)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(num);
         }
    }
}
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the value of the textbox and split it on comma.  You would then have a string array of the values that should be adequate for further use.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/split